# sqlalchemy.exc.TimeoutError: QueuePool limit of size 5 overflow 10 reached, connection timed out, timeout 30.00

Tags: python-3.x, aiogram, sqlite3, sqlalchemy

Всем доброго дня, появилась проблема, в которой не могу разобраться.

```
@logger.catch
async def sub_select(id: int):
    session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    with session() as s:
        sub = s.query(datab_model.Subs).filter(datab_model.Subs.id == id).first()
    return sub
```

Вот мой способ достать данные из таблицы (я так делал со всеми таблицами).

```
async def statistic(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.finish()
    await message.answer('Собираю данные...')
    purchases = await select_db.select_purchases()
    cheques = await select_db.select_cheques()
    users = await select_db.select_users()
    subs_users = await select_db.select_users_subs_subs_id_not_0()
    ...
```

Но почему то, когда я выполняю этот код, у меня выходит такая ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/root/ManagerBuildBot/mainBot.py", line 33, in <module>
    executor.start_polling(dp, on_startup=on_startup)
    │        │             │              └ <function on_startup at 0x7fce169b7010>
    │        │             └ <aiogram.dispatcher.dispatcher.Dispatcher object at 0x7fce16d484c0>
    │        └ <function start_polling at 0x7fce17a8c9d0>
    └ <module 'aiogram.utils.executor' from '/root/ManagerBuildBot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/utils/executor.py'>

  File "/root/ManagerBuildBot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/utils/executor.py", line 45, in start_polling
    executor.start_polling(
    │        └ <function Executor.start_polling at 0x7fce17a8d3f0>
    └ <aiogram.utils.executor.Executor object at 0x7fce199cfb80>
  File "/root/ManagerBuildBot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/utils/executor.py", line 323, in start_polling
    loop.run_forever()
    │    └ <function BaseEventLoop.run_forever at 0x7fce191d3880>
    └ <_UnixSelectorEventLoop running=True closed=False debug=False>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 603, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
    │    └ <function BaseEventLoop._run_once at 0x7fce18fe13f0>
    └ <_UnixSelectorEventLoop running=True closed=False debug=False>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1909, in _run_once
    handle._run()
    │      └ <function Handle._run at 0x7fce19134dc0>
    └ <Handle <TaskStepMethWrapper object at 0x7fce15f14790>()>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/events.py", line 80, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
    │    │            │    │           │    └ <member '_args' of 'Handle' objects>
    │    │            │    │           └ <Handle <TaskStepMethWrapper object at 0x7fce15f14790>()>
    │    │            │    └ <member '_callback' of 'Handle' objects>
    │    │            └ <Handle <TaskStepMethWrapper object at 0x7fce15f14790>()>
    │    └ <member '_context' of 'Handle' objects>
    └ <Handle <TaskStepMethWrapper object at 0x7fce15f14790>()>
  File "/root/ManagerBuildBot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/handler.py", line 116, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
                     │           │        │       └ {}
                     │           │        └ (<Update {"update_id": 102773831, "message": {"message_id": 3018, "from": {"id": 5840903752, "is_bot": false, "first_name": "...
                     │           └ <bound method Dispatcher.process_update of <aiogram.dispatcher.dispatcher.Dispatcher object at 0x7fce16d484c0>>
                     └ Handler.HandlerObj(handler=<bound method Dispatcher.process_update of <aiogram.dispatcher.dispatcher.Dispatcher object at 0x7...
  File "/root/ManagerBuildBot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py", line 256, in process_update
    return await self.message_handlers.notify(update.message)
                 │    │                │      │      └ <aiogram.types.fields.Field object at 0x7fce17b46680>
                 │    │                │      └ <Update {"update_id": 102773831, "message": {"message_id": 3018, "from": {"id": 5840903752, "is_bot": false, "first_name": "K...
                 │    │                └ <function Handler.notify at 0x7fce17baf490>
                 │    └ <aiogram.dispatcher.handler.Handler object at 0x7fce16d499c0>
                 └ <aiogram.dispatcher.dispatcher.Dispatcher object at 0x7fce16d484c0>
> File "/root/ManagerBuildBot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/handler.py", line 116, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
                     │           │        │       └ {'state': <aiogram.dispatcher.storage.FSMContext object at 0x7fce15f17d30>}
                     │           │        └ (<Message {"message_id": 3018, "from": {"id": 5840903752, "is_bot": false, "first_name": "Karabok", "username": "NoverLove", ...
                     │           └ <function statistic at 0x7fce16997b50>
                     └ Handler.HandlerObj(handler=<function statistic at 0x7fce16997b50>, spec=FullArgSpec(args=['message', 'state'], varargs=None, ...

  File "/root/ManagerBuildBot/bot/commands/admins/cmd_statistic.py", line 26, in statistic
    for purchase in purchases: all_purchase += purchase.amount_pay
                    │          └ 0
                    └ <sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query object at 0x7fce15f17f70>

  File "/root/ManagerBuildBot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2832, in __iter__
    result = self._iter()
             │    └ <function Query._iter at 0x7fce16e0d2d0>
             └ <sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query object at 0x7fce15f17f70>
  File "/root/ManagerBuildBot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2846, in _iter
    result: Union[ScalarResult[_T], Result[_T]] = self.session.execute(
            │                  │    │      │      │    │       └ <function Session.execute at 0x7fce16e7f1c0>
            │                  │    │      │      │    └ <sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session object at 0x7fce15f17f10>
            │                  │    │      │      └ <sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query object at 0x7fce15f17f70>
            │                  │    │      └ ~_T
            │                  │    └ <class 'sqlalchemy.engine.result.Result'>
            │                  └ ~_T
            └ typing.Union
  File "/root/ManagerBuildBot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2246, in execute
    return self._execute_internal(
           │    └ <function Session._execute_internal at 0x7fce16e7f130>
           └ <sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session object at 0x7fce15f17f10>
  File "/root/ManagerBuildBot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2131, in _execute_internal
    conn = self._connection_for_bind(bind)
           │    │                    └ Engine(sqlite+pysqlite:////root/ManagerBuildBot/bot/data/database.db)
           │    └ <function Session._connection_for_bind at 0x7fce16e7f0a0>
           └ <sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session object at 0x7fce15f17f10>
  File "/root/ManagerBuildBot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1998, in _connection_for_bind
    return trans._connection_for_bind(engine, execution_options)
           │     │                    │       └ None
           │     │                    └ Engine(sqlite+pysqlite:////root/ManagerBuildBot/bot/data/database.db)
           │     └ <function SessionTransaction._connection_for_bind at 0x7fce16e7de10>
           └ <sqlalchemy.orm.session.SessionTransaction object at 0x7fce1613b580>
  File "<string>", line 2, in _connection_for_bind
  File "/root/ManagerBuildBot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/state_changes.py", line 139, in _go
    ret_value = fn(self, *arg, **kw)
                │  │      │      └ {}
                │  │      └ (Engine(sqlite+pysqlite:////root/ManagerBuildBot/bot/data/database.db), None)
                │  └ <sqlalchemy.orm.session.SessionTransaction object at 0x7fce1613b580>
                └ <function SessionTransaction._connection_for_bind at 0x7fce16e7dcf0>
  File "/root/ManagerBuildBot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1123, in _connection_for_bind
    conn = bind.connect()
           │    └ <function Engine.connect at 0x7fce171470a0>
           └ Engine(sqlite+pysqlite:////root/ManagerBuildBot/bot/data/database.db)
  File "/root/ManagerBuildBot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3264, in connect
    return self._connection_cls(self)
           │    │               └ Engine(sqlite+pysqlite:////root/ManagerBuildBot/bot/data/database.db)
           │    └ <class 'sqlalchemy.engine.base.Connection'>
           └ Engine(sqlite+pysqlite:////root/ManagerBuildBot/bot/data/database.db)
  File "/root/ManagerBuildBot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 145, in __init__
    self._dbapi_connection = engine.raw_connection()
    │                        │      └ <function Engine.raw_connection at 0x7fce17147130>
    │                        └ Engine(sqlite+pysqlite:////root/ManagerBuildBot/bot/data/database.db)
    └ <sqlalchemy.engine.base.Connection object at 0x7fce15f17010>
  File "/root/ManagerBuildBot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3288, in raw_connection
    return self.pool.connect()
           │    │    └ <function Pool.connect at 0x7fce178beb00>
           │    └ <sqlalchemy.pool.impl.QueuePool object at 0x7fce16d4ae60>
           └ Engine(sqlite+pysqlite:////root/ManagerBuildBot/bot/data/database.db)
  File "/root/ManagerBuildBot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 452, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
           │                │         └ <sqlalchemy.pool.impl.QueuePool object at 0x7fce16d4ae60>
           │                └ <classmethod(<function _ConnectionFairy._checkout at 0x7fce178dc430>)>
           └ <class 'sqlalchemy.pool.base._ConnectionFairy'>
  File "/root/ManagerBuildBot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 1267, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
            │                 │        └ <sqlalchemy.pool.impl.QueuePool object at 0x7fce16d4ae60>
            │                 └ <classmethod(<function _ConnectionRecord.checkout at 0x7fce178bf520>)>
            └ <class 'sqlalchemy.pool.base._ConnectionRecord'>
  File "/root/ManagerBuildBot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 716, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
          │    └ <function QueuePool._do_get at 0x7fce178df1c0>
          └ <sqlalchemy.pool.impl.QueuePool object at 0x7fce16d4ae60>
  File "/root/ManagerBuildBot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 158, in _do_get
    raise exc.TimeoutError(
          │   └ <class 'sqlalchemy.exc.TimeoutError'>
          └ <module 'sqlalchemy.exc' from '/root/ManagerBuildBot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/exc.py'>

sqlalchemy.exc.TimeoutError: QueuePool limit of size 5 overflow 10 reached, connection timed out, timeout 30.00 (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/3o7r)
```

В остальных функциях, где я получаю данные, все отлично.